# Oracle SQL String Manipulation

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

My field contains short codes that I want to access, such as C-COR3.

The issue is some records have additional information (F and H with numbers). An example is C-COR3 F1.54H19, I only care about C-COR3. Anything after "F" I want to ignore.

Code below works, but only if I hard-code the full F1.54H19. I want to use wildcards to abstract this for other occurrences that have F and H info in the field. (Ex C-R3 F0.18H18 -> C-R3 or C-COR3 F0.23H8.5 -> C-COR3), note varying short code string lengths.

/* Translates C-COR3 F1.54H19 to C-COR3. */

```
select distinct SUBSTR(lud_code_short,1,INSTR(lud_code_short, 'F1.54H19')-2) 
from rep_dba.mytable
```

I've read that `SUBSTR` does not allow wildcards, but have had no luck trying my hand at `REGEXP_INSTR` and `REGEX_SUBSTR` instead. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What can you rely on? That is, are your codes always the first 6 chars? Or does the unwanted part always begin with F/H and F/H never appear in the "good part" of the string? ...

Comment: Hi Aleksej,

The F and H always come at the end of the string if they appear (they may not always appear). The length of the first part (C-COR) varies and so does the #'s that follow F and H (sometimes decimals sometimes not). Looking at it I actually see I have one that have F but not H. Its a mix bag unfortunately.

Comment: Is there always a space?  For example, can you just return whatever comes before the space?

Comment: There is always a space between the stuff I want and the F/H items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "code" is always the first continuous sequence of **non-space** characters (and that there are no leading spaces - if there are, that's easy to handle), you could do something like this. Note the `str || ' '` in the call to `instr()` - that takes care of the case when the input string has no spaces in it to begin with. Also notice the last input - since there are no spaces anywhere, the output is the same as the input. (Showing that if the "code" is not always separated from the "additional information" by at least one space, the solution would not work.)

```
with
  test_data (str) as (
    select 'C-COR3 F14H2.5' from dual union all
    select 'C-AB3'          from dual union all
    select null             from dual union all
    select 'C-AB2F14H2.5'   from dual
  )
select str, substr(str, 1, instr(str || ' ', ' ') - 1) as code
from   test_data
;

STR            CODE          
-------------- --------------
C-COR3 F14H2.5 C-COR3        
C-AB3          C-AB3         

C-AB2F14H2.5   C-AB2F14H2.5
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified this and it works for what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `regexp_replace` within your query like below

```sql
SELECT 
    regexp_replace('C-COR3 F14H2.5', '(C-[[:alnum:]]+) [FH].*', '\1') 
FROM dual;
```